# How to get a string from an sql query in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, string, email

How to get a string returned from an sql query. MY code i have is:

```
    $to = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT email FROM register WHERE ID = '$i'");
```

This returns an object which im assuming needs to be converted (something I'm also not sure how to do (PHP noob!)). I need to know how to get a sting from the database in the first place. Also I only need one field of the row.

Comment: Come on. You can look that up in a million tutorials on the net.

Comment: @juergend Not just the net, but this site even.

Comment: When you show such a small amount of effort, not many people are going to help you...

Comment: @crush, I don't think so. That's for `PDO`, not `mysqli`.

Comment: @juergend: It's posts like these that make me wish we still had the option to close posts because a minimal understanding of the problem and a reasonable amount of effort was not displayed.

Comment: @Chris Being that he's a noob, there's no reason for him not to start using PDO.

Comment: Thanks for the insults guys. nice of you... :)

Comment: @crush, I agree that learning PDO now is a good idea. But that question is not a duplicate of this one.

Comment: what about looking at php.net?

Comment: @Chris The question was how to get a string from mysql in PHP, not How to get a string from mysql using the mysqli extension. ;)

Comment: @crush, Except, if you look at his code, he is already using the `mysqli_*` extension which is commendable considering how many people still post up code showing they are using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions.

Answer (score 1):

look at this link, it contains all the information that you need, but you need to apply it yourself, we can help once you try. Everyone starts at some point. Best of luck! http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-string-functions.htm